# Javafx how to create buttons via function?

Tags: java, button, javafx, scene

Please help me make it works. It freezes instead of changing Scenes.
It works fine when buttons are created this way:

```
Button b1 = new Button("Go to s2");
b1.setOnAction(e -> window.setScene(s2));
Button b2 = new Button("Go to s1");
b2.setOnAction(e -> window.setScene(s1));
```

But I'd like to make it more elegant...

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    Stage window;
    Scene s1,s2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        window = primaryStage;

        Button b1 = makeButton("Go to s2", s2);
        Button b2 = makeButton("Go to s1", s1);

        s1 = new Scene(b1);
        s2 = new Scene(b2);

        primaryStage.setScene(s1);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public Button makeButton(String name, Scene destScene)  {
        Button button = new Button(name);
        button.setOnAction(e -> window.setScene(destScene));
        return button;
    }
}
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the order for how everything is initialized:

```
Button b1 = makeButton("Go to s2", s2);
Button b2 = makeButton("Go to s1", s1);

s1 = new Scene(b1);
s2 = new Scene(b2);
```

When you call `makeButton`, you pass in the *value of the reference* currently stored in `s1` and `s2`. Since it was never initialized, it takes the default value of `null`. This doesn't get changed when you letter set `s1` and `s2` because of the copied reference.

You don't have the same problem in the first case, because you never make a copy of `s1` and `s2`. Instead, you have the `EventHandler` refer to the field in the current instance of `Main`, which does get correctly updated once you set it. So your original code is something equivalent to this:

```
Button b1 = new Button("Go to s2");
b1.setOnAction(e -> window.setScene(this.s2));
```

So you're copying the reference to the enclosing `Main` instance, rather than the reference to the button itself.

I don't see any trivial fix for it unfortunately. The easiest solution I see would be to change your function to `makeButton(String, EventHandler<ActionEvent>)`, and call it like this:

```
Button b1 = makeButton("Go to s2", e -> window.setScene(s2));
```

Not as nice as what you want, but it should work.

Another possible solution is to put all of your `Button`s into an array, and then pass an index into that array into `makeButton`. That would look like tihs:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    Stage window;
    Scene[] scenes = new Scene[2];

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        window = primaryStage;

        Button b1 = makeButton("Go to s2", 1);
        Button b2 = makeButton("Go to s1", 0);

        scenes[0] = new Scene(b1);
        scenes[1] = new Scene(b2);

        primaryStage.setScene(scenes[0]);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public Button makeButton(String name, int destScene)  {
        Button button = new Button(name);
        button.setOnAction(e -> window.setScene(scenes[destScene]));
        return button;
    }
}
```

That changes the `EventHandler` to reference a field of `Main` (`scenes`) rather than a local variable (`destScene`).